# Tool to monitor jms messages

Tags: java, jvm, jms, wildfly

Is there any open source tool to monitor the jms: message broker, deployed consumers, stats of sent/produced or received/consumed messages trafic etc in cluster mode on runtime? I.e i want to attach to running server (e.g. Wildfly ) and monitor the jms stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JMS API doesn't define anything related to statistics or metrics. Because of this there are no general purpose tools for monitoring JMS brokers. Every tool to monitor the metrics you want will be specific to the JMS broker. If you're using Wildfly then I would recommend you use their [CLI tool](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Command+Line+Interface) or possibly even JMX.

Comment: Please note that you can enable statistics on wildfly to get some metrics

Comment: and how would one do that?